# Method for drooping mesh vertices over rounded objects

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, vertices

So i'm modeling a gun and i want to cover the top of the barrel with a shape that droops over the mesh like a table cloth over a table.

[image: before]

Me being new to blender, i guess the shrinkwrap modifier is the go-to answer for this but it doesnt product the exact result i want.

[image: after]

How would i get the shape i want for this object without manually having to play with the vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from the looks of it, I'd say that the object you want to shrink has a way too low vertex count to fit the model. Try to add some loop cuts and then try the shrink wrap modifier again.

Depending on what you want the end result look like, it's also possible to copy a part of your mesh, convert that part into a new object (hit P) and go from there.

There is also the possibility of using physics but I never tried it with solid objects.

Comment: Thanks mate, i thought the mesh would automatically take care of adding vertices for me. That never occurred to me.